# Sequence of uses cases

Tags: uml, use-case

I would like to represent a functionality that add data on a database with historization.

I hesitate to put an include between "add" and "historize" but that would mean that an actor wanting to add must historize before, as for authenticate use case, an actor must authenticate before perform some actions...

How can I represent that ?

Comment: If it's a functionality then it's not a use case.

Comment: in some cases a feature is exactly the same thing, in other cases, this is not...

Comment: I'd recommend you read Bittner/Spence about use cases before arguing that way.

Comment: Hu. I know these discussions and it will blast any question here (so better remove that part unless you want your question closed). For me a UC must represent added value for its actor. That is true for business and technical level. The problem is that on the latter people start talking about functions as being use cases. It's harder to find the border the lower you go with UCs. It's better staying on business level. Activities/actions are nice on tech level, though.

Answer (score 1):

As Thomas Kilian I have doubt about you have an UC "add" and an UC "historize", seems at implementation level rather than an UC level.

If I well understand for you to have *UC_add include UC_historize* means *an actor wanting to add must historize before*, this is false :

- An include is not a notation for a precondition
- The UML norm do not says the behavior of the included UC is inserted *before* the behavior of the including UC, just it is inserted *into*, without more constraint about the moment this is done.

Anyway, if you really have these 2 UCs and the behavior of the UC_historize is included in the behavior of the UC_add, the include is correct.

Comment: I always learned that an included use case was mandatory perform before.
If UC_order include UC_authenticate, I must authenticate before, and all the examples on the internet go in this direction.

Comment: The norm, just the norm :-) Read carefully  [formal-17-12-05.pdf](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1/PDF) §18.1.3.3 page 641

Comment: And to be complete, the authentication must generally not be made through an include because the include is mandatory (done each time), it must be done through an extend with the condition _not yet logged_ and an _ExtensionPoint_ specifying _at the beginning_. (there is no _IncludePoint_ in UML ;-) )

Comment: `Login` us no use case at all. It's a constraint.

Comment: @Thomas Kilian this is not because to be logged is a constaint for other UCs than to login is not an UC. For instance if the system is an application for the mail the UCs consult/send/read mail required to be logged, but to login is also an UC, and to logout an other one.

Comment: @bruno The norm says "All of the behavior of the included UseCase is executed at a single location in the included UseCase before execution of
the including UseCase is resumed." The included use case is executed before or during including use case, but not after. So for log history, this is not a use case but this part must be execute after some uses cases so must I represent on use case diagram or only on flow of events ?

Comment: @user "at the end" doesn't mean "after", the included UC can be executed at the end of the including UC